# Spring mongo can't group by month from timestamp saved as long

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a set of mongodb documens saved with a timestamp value as long, and I can't get the month. I have the following code to make the query:

```
 Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.project( FleetChargeSession.FieldNames.CONNECTED_TIME, FleetChargeSession.FieldNames.TOTAL_COST)
                        .and(DateOperators.Month.month(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf(FleetChargeSession.FieldNames.CONNECTED_TIME)))
                        .as("month"),
                Aggregation.group("month")
                        .sum(FleetChargeSession.FieldNames.TOTAL_COST).as("total")
        );

AggregationResults<FleetChargeSession> groupResults = reportingMongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, FleetChargeSession.class, FleetChargeSession.class);
```

When I execute this I have an Exception because I don't have an string to convert to Date:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 241 (ConversionFailure): 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: long with value 1668675829825' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: long with value 1668675829825", "code": 241, "codeName": "ConversionFailure"}
```

I couldn't find anything to convert my Long timestamp value to get the month. Could someone help me with this?